# Cannot upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5 because of Temando

Tags: magento2, composer, temando

After running this command:
`composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5`

I get the following error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping[1.6.2, 2.0.0].

```
- Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping[2.0.0, 1.6.2].

- Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping[2.0.0, 1.6.2].

- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].

- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5].

- Installation request for temando/module-shipping (locked at 1.6.2) -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[1.6.2].
```

Also without any extra extensions in composer.json and app/code

Also after manually removing /vendor/temando

Also after removing composer.lock

Comment: check this link --- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/question-about-migrating-from-2-28-to-latest-version-of-magento/m-p/139364/highlight/true#M2238

Comment: Hi Mohit, this does not work:

"Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2]"

Comment: A relevant Temando talk found on Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27316

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some fooman extensions were causing this.